# How to import InfoType or other types from google-cloud/dlp for typescript in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-dlp

Working with Google cloud DLP and nodejs. After `import DLP from "@google-cloud/dlp`, how can I import `InfoType, Likelihood, IInspectContentRequest` and other types from the library as it contains all types.

Comment: Refer to this [Cloud Data Loss Prevention Overview](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-dlp-overview) which may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution `import {protos} from "@google-cloud/dlp`